# How can I receive post from node js sent with form data from Angular frontend

Tags: node.js, angular, multipartform-data

I posted data on angular front end as formData like this.

```
postButton(name: string): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', name);
    return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/url, formData);
}
```

And I receive data on Node.js front end like this.

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.post('/api/url', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  res.status(200).json({
    'message': 'OK',
  });
});
```

But I get {},empty value.
what is wrong in my code?
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

According to my knowledge, if you are sending some file then using `FormData` is useful. In other scenario's like this in which you are just sending plain text. You can just send a normal `json` object and it will work. You can try this.

```
postButton(name: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/url, { name });
}
```

In case you really want to use `FormData` then you need to install a npm package as:

```
npm install multer
```

And change your `app.js` to:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();

app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(upload.array()); 
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/api/url', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Now, what `multer` does is, it supports `multi-part` form submission. And `FromData` uses that. To get the data from request body you need to install and configure `multer`.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I tried like that way and that works correctly. But I should to send data with form data.

Comment: @JordanMicle Answer Updated

Comment: Great, it works correctly, Thanks for your help, Muhammad

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `Content-Type` header:

```
postButton(name: string): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', name);

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().delete('Content-Type')
    };

    return this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + '/url, formData, httpOptions);
}
```

When the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) send method sends a [FormData Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), it automatically sets the content type header with the appropriate boundary. When the Angular http service overrides the default content type, the server will get a content type header without the proper boundary.